# Socket.emit not work with Up and Back button _ Android

Tags: android, socket.io

Have you seen this bug before ?

1/ I create Activity A and intent to Activity B. At Activity B, click back button on top left, in actionBar , then click button on Activity A to access Activity B again. First time, emit success to server, second time fail.

2/ What could I do so far ?

- Check mSocket.connect() at Activity B: always false, even emit success.
- Add socket in Activity B: rise one more time emit success at Activity B, after that, fail again.
- There is no socket in Activity A, only B has. Back button on android phone work but back button on actionBar ... fail emit to server at second time.

  For those who have same problem. I still find no way...until your help.

Best,
Quang.

Answer (score 0):

[Water in fire]

- Reason: problem with UP and Back button, overlap task
- Solution:

  - Block back button on android phone
  - Add singleTask
- Result: Socket.emit success to server with multiple time send.

  D*** it!